# Getting at form meta-data for an Access form that is not loaded

Tags: forms, ms-access

How do I get at the information for an Access form that is NOT loaded? (Loaded forms are pretty easy - via UserForms, but I specifically want something that will address a form whether or not it is loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the information for all forms (loaded or not) via the `CurrentProject.AllForms` collection:

```
Dim frm As Form
Set frm = Application.CurrentProject.AllForms("FormName")
'' print out the Record Source for the form
Debug.Print frm.RecordSource
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, UserForms aren't part of Access, I am assuming you are talking about VBA userforms like those available in Excel VBA IDE, but these aren't part of the Access VBA implementation (for the obvious reason that Access has it's own forms). Also, the code that Gord shows won't run because the AllForms property is a collection of AllForm objects which aren't the same as the Access Form object, and they don't have the RecordSource property.
But, to answer your question, you can use the AllForms collection to see if a particular form is loaded. If it is you can check any info you want directly. If it isn't you can load it but keep it hidden, then you can check any info you want to.